# Match and replace first and last character in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I would like to remove `%` characters from the start and the end of a string. For example:

```
string s = "%hello%world%";
```

Desired result: `hello%world`.

I know that I can fix this with some if cases combined with `StartsWith()`, `EndsWith()` etc. But I'm looking for a cleaner solution.

I suppose regexp is the way to go here, and that's where I need your help.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple `%`s at the beginning or end of your string?

Comment: @juharr They should remain untouched. So I guess the solutions below works fine.

Comment: yeah, use the regex and not the `Trim` option then.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's no need for a regular expression. Just use this:

```
string result = input.Trim('%');
```

But if you really need a regular expression, you'd need to use start (`^`) and end (`$`) anchors, like this:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "^%|%$", "");
```

Comment: Those are technically not the same as `Trim` will remove multiple occurrences of `%` and the regex only replace one.

Comment: Thanks. And if I would like to replace the first and last `%` with something else? Trim it and wrap it? Never mind, just saw your update.

Comment: @Johan Well, in that case, you might want to use the `Regex` solution. Also, as *juharr* points out, the `Trim` solution can remove more than one character from the beginning / end; the `Regex` solution removes at most one.

Answer (score 5):

```
s = s.Trim('%');
```

Regex is not the way to go for simple stuff, but if you insist:

```
s = Regex.Replace(s, @"^%+|%+$", "");
```

Comment: How do I change `%` to `*`? I believe the * is used for something else in regexp?

Comment: @Johan In that case, escape the `*` with a backslash: `"@^\*+|\*+$"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
 string s = "%hello%world";
 char c = '%';
 int indexBegin = s[0] == c ? 1 : 0;
 int indexEnd = s[s.Length - 1] == c ? 1 : 0;
 s = s.Substring(indexBegin, s.Length - (indexEnd+indexBegin));
```

Comment: What if the input is `"hello%world%"`? I think if OP *knew* that all input strings would contain a `%` at the beginning and end, I doubt they would've posted this question.

Comment: What if the input was "@hello%world@"? So it depends on the situation, but I can agree with your comment.

Comment: This is a good approach, but I think you should include some code to check for `%`. It wouldn't take much (something like `s[0] == '%' ? 1 : 0`), but I think it's necessary to truly answer the question.

Comment: Close but the second parameter can be either `s.Length` minus 0, 1, or 2 (depending on whether there are 0, 1, or 2 characters to trim). I recommend you calculate the number of characters to trim from the start and end, and then subtract both numbers from the length to get your second parameter.